# Uniqueness of direct product of two $A$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, algebras

$
\newcommand{\cn}{\colon}
\newcommand{\<}{\leqslant}
$
Let $k$ be a field.

**Def.** *Algebra* $A$ is associative ring with unity and a ring homomorphism $f\cn k\to A$ such that $f(1_k)=1_A$ and $f(a)x=xf(a)$ for all $x\in A$.

**Def.** *$A$-module* $V$ is a vector space over k with a bilinear map $(A,V)\to V,~(a,v)\mapsto av$, such that $1v=v$ and $a(bv)=(ab)v$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $v\in V$.

Let $V_1$ be $A_1$-module and $V_2$ be $A_2$-module. I want to **prove or disprove** that any $(A_1\times A_2)$-module $V_1\times V_2$ is such that $(a_1,a_2)(v_1,v_2)=(a_1v_1,a_2v_2)$ (exercise 3 after chapter 1 from **Kassel's Quantum Groups**). Structures on products are defined elementwise here.

Using bilinearity I obtain decomposition $(a_1,a_2)(v_1,v_2)=(a_1,0)(v_1,0)+(a_1,0)(0,v_2)+(0,a_2)(v_1,0)+(0,a_2)(0,v_2)$. So I've come to four simplier cases. Another thing I have is that $V=V_1\times V_2=U_1\oplus U_2$, where $U_1=\left\{v\in V\cn (1,0)v=v\right\},~U_2=\left\{v\in V\cn (0,1)v=v\right\}$ are subspaces of $V$. Also I see that $(a_1,0)v\in U_1$ and $(a_2,0)v\in U_2$ for all $v\in V,~a_1\in A_1,~a_2\in A_2$. Any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit.** The exact statement is

> Let $A_1,A_2$ be some algebras, $V_1$ an $A_1$-module, and $V_2$ an
> $A_2$-module. Show that the equality $(a_1,a_2)(v_1,v_2)=(a_1v_1,a_2v_2)$
> defines the $A_1\times A_2$-module structure at $V_1\times V_2$. Prove that
> any $A_1\times A_2$-module has this form.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I fear your claim does not hold in that generality, in particular your mixed mid terms might actually not be $0$. This is in particular often of design and one of the main motivations between a lot of constructions, for example semi-orthogonal decompositions or upper triangular matrix algebras! 
I.e. you need to somehow exclude the possibility that $A_1$ operates on $V_2$, which as you are working over $k$-algebras already happens if you have an augmentation.

Comment: @Enkidu Thank you for the answer! I have no augmentation here. In order to obtain counterexample, I should take $V_1$ and $V_2$ as upper triangular matrix algebras over $A_1=A_2=k$? Which action $(A_1\times A_2)\times (V_1\times V_2)\to V_1\times V_2$ I should use?

Comment: any upper triangular one that cannot be diagonalized should do the trick

Comment: @Enkidu Do you mean the Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices? But it is not associative

Comment: It sounds like you have probably mangled the statement of the exercise you are trying to solve.  What is its exact statement?

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right. In fact the exercise asks the reader to show that the structure described makes $V_1\times V_2$ into an $A_1\times A_2$-module, and then to show that every $A_1\times A_2$-module is of this form (presumably up to isomorphism, although this is not explicitly stated). Nothing to do with different module structures on $V_1\times V_2$.

Comment: @EricWofsey added the exact statement